# How can i make the glowing effect behind a video?

Tags: javascript, css, video, bootstrap-4, glow

In the latest **Youtube** update, ***Google*** has put a **glow** effect behind the videos. He calls it "cinematicmode" which takes the video in question and creates that beam of light while the video is playing. I'm with a Boostrap5 project trying to replicate the same format that youtube has but I don't know how to do it. I don't know if it can be done with JS or with CSS or with some external library.

The code I am working on:

```
.container {
  max-width: 980px;
}

.title {
  color: white;
}
.bd-placeholder-img {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.b-example-divider {
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    inset 0 0.125em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.b-example-vr {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bi {
  vertical-align: -0.125em;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 2.75rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

video {
  border-radius: 5%;
  width: 100%;
}

.video-tam {
  width: 220px;
  height: 140px;
}

.tit {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tit-video {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.descrip {
  color: white;
}

.img-logo {
  width: 30vh;
}
.img-user{
  width: 10vh;
}

.cont-descrip {
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-color: #dc3444;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 2%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
}




body{

  background: #304FFE;
} 

.form-control:focus {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: 0;
   box-shadow: none !important;
}


.dashboard-header .navbar {
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6f2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px 0px rgba(82, 63, 105, 0.13);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px 0px rgba(82, 63, 105, 0.13);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  min-height: 60px;
}



.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #007bff;
}
.navbar-brand:hover{
  color: #007bff;
}
.navbar-right-top {}

.navbar-right-top .nav-item {
  border-right: 1px solid #e6e6f2;
}

.navbar-right-top .nav-item:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.navbar-right-top .nav-item .nav-link {
  padding: 13px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #82849f;
}


/* --  top-search-bar ---  */

.top-search-bar {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-right: 24px;
}


/* ------  Notification Dropdown --------  */

.notification {}

.notification-dropdown {
  min-width: 320px;
}

.notification-dropdown,
.connection-dropdown,
.nav-user-dropdown {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.notification-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #3d405c;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #fffffe;
}

.notification-list {}

.notification-list .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-left: transparent;
  border-right: transparent;
}

.notification-list .list-group-item.active {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #3d405c;
  background-color: #f7f7fb;
  border-color: #e1e1e7;
}

.notification-list .list-group-item-action:focus,
.list-group-item-action:hover {
  color: #404040;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f7f7fb;
}

.notification-list .list-group-item:last-child {}

.notification-info {}

.notification-info .notification-date {
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #71748d;
}

.notification .dropdown-toggle::after,
.connection .dropdown-toggle::after,
.nav-user .dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: .255em;
  vertical-align: .255em;
  content: "";
  border: none;
}

.notification-list-user-img {
  float: left;
}

.notification-list-user-block {
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.notification-list-user-name {
  color: #5969ff;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.list-footer,
.conntection-footer {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #5969ff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.list-footer a,
.conntection-footer a {
  color: #fff;
}

.list-footer a:hover,
.conntection-footer a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.indicator {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 23px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ef172c;
  animation: .9s infinite beatHeart;
  transform-origin: center;
}

@keyframes beatHeart {
  0% {
      transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  25% {
      transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  40% {
      transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  60% {
      transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
      transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}


/* ------  Connection --------  */

.connection {}

.connection-dropdown {}

.connection-list {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.connection-item {
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 7px 4px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #3d405c;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.connection-item img {
  width: 32px;
}

.connection-item:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6f2;
}

.connection-item span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* ----- User Nav Dropdown -----*/

.nav-user {}

.nav-user-dropdown {
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 230px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav-user-name {}

.nav-user-info {
  background-color: #5969ff;
  line-height: 1.4;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}

.nav-user-info .status {
  float: left;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0px;
}

.nav-user-dropdown {}

.nav-user-dropdown .dropdown-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 22px 15px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #686972;
  text-align: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 0.4;
}

.nav-user-dropdown .dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7fb;
}

/*---- User icon sizes ---*/

.user-avatar-xxl {
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}

.user-avatar-xl {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
}

.user-avatar-lg {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
}

.user-avatar-md {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}

.user-avatar-sm {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}

.user-avatar-xs {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
}



.avatar {
  width: 2.25rem;
  height: 2.25rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #F7F9FA;
  background: #F7F9FA;
  color: #fff;
}


.media-attachment div.avatar {
  border: none;
}

.avatar.bg-primary {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.avatar.bg-primary i {
  font-size: 14px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta
      name="author"
      content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors"
    />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>YouFlix</title>

    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.104.2" />


    <link
      rel="canonical"
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/checkout/"
    />

    <link href="../assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

  </head>

  <body class="bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <main>


        <div class="py-5 text-center">
          <img
            class="d-block mx-auto mb-4 img-logo"
            src="Logo_negro_negro.webp"
            alt="YouFlix"
          />
          <h2 class="title">YouFlix</h2>
          <p class="lead text-light">Tu Web de Videos preferida</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row g-5">
          <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
            <video class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" controls>
              <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <span
              class="tit-video badge bg-danger rounded-pill w-100 text-start"
              >TITULO DEL VIDEO</span
            >
            <div class="cont-descrip">
              <p class="descrip">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea,
                est? Error, enim. Esse, provident vitae aliquam, illum
                distinctio est quis quidem minus quisquam ullam quos, nisi neque
                necessitatibus voluptas dolorem.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 order-md-last">
            <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
              <span class="badge bg-danger rounded-pill">TUS VIDEOS</span>
              <span class="badge bg-danger rounded-pill">100</span>
            </h4>

            <ul class="list-group mb-5">
              <li
                class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-sm bg-secondary"
              >
                <div>
                  <video
                    class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-tam"
                    controls
                  >
                    <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                  <span class="text-light">12:04</span>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li
                class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-sm bg-secondary"
              >
                <div>
                  <video
                    class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-tam"
                    controls
                  >
                    <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                  <span class="text-light">12:04</span>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li
                class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-sm bg-secondary"
              >
                <div>
                  <video
                    class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-tam"
                    controls
                  >
                    <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                  <span class="text-light">12:04</span>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li
                class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-sm bg-secondary"
              >
                <div>
                  <video
                    class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-tam"
                    controls
                  >
                    <source src="videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                  </video>
                  <span class="text-light m-2">12:04</span>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>

      <footer class="my-5 pt-5 text-muted text-center text-small">
        <p class="mb-1">&copy; 2022–2023 YouFlix</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="form-validation.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Phone effect]

[image: Phone effect][image]

I have not found any of the web format.
Someone could help me? Thanks in advance. :)

I tried to use `backdrop-filter` in CSS but does not fit with my description

Comment: Add the HTML, the CSS has very little meaning if we do not see where, and to what it applies to. BTW it doesn't appear to be a glow, it's more like a partial extension of the video poster image which is blurred.

Comment: @zer00ne Hi, its on the post firstly the CSS and then the HTML

Comment: What you said makes very little sense. You must post the HTML, the CSS cannot be accurately assessed without knowing how the HTML is setup -- this is fundamental

Comment: @Imanoldt I'm not seeing this option called _"Cinematic mode"_ on my Youtube player, Do you have a link to a video where this option is available?

Comment: @VC.One i am going to update the post, look at it.

Comment: @zer00ne it is bellow the CSS the HTML, so it has all sense

Comment: there is a js library for that but i am looking for it since a while and just cant find it. its something like ambilight.js or so. will get back to this thread as soon as i found it
Edit: https://github.com/brunos3d/video-ambilight does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this:

```js
const VideoAmbilight = ({ videoSrc }) => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  let intervalId;

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvasElement = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvasElement.getContext('2d');

    const videoElement = videoRef.current;

    function repaintAmbilight() {
      context.drawImage(
        videoElement,
        0,
        0,
        videoElement.videoWidth,
        videoElement.videoHeight
      );
    }

    function startAmbilightRepaint() {
      intervalId = window.setInterval(repaintAmbilight, 1000 / 30);
    }

    function stopAmbilightRepaint() {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }

    videoElement.addEventListener('play', startAmbilightRepaint);
    videoElement.addEventListener('pause', stopAmbilightRepaint);
    videoElement.addEventListener('ended', stopAmbilightRepaint);
    videoElement.addEventListener('seeked', repaintAmbilight);
    videoElement.addEventListener('loadeddata', repaintAmbilight);

    return () => {
      stopAmbilightRepaint();
      videoElement.removeEventListener('play', startAmbilightRepaint);
      videoElement.removeEventListener('pause', stopAmbilightRepaint);
      videoElement.removeEventListener('ended', stopAmbilightRepaint);
      videoElement.removeEventListener('seeked', repaintAmbilight);
      videoElement.removeEventListener('loadeddata', repaintAmbilight);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Proxy the video request through Next.js server to avoid cross-origin issues
    const fetchVideo = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(videoSrc, { responseType: 'blob' });
        const videoBlob = response.data;
        const videoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
        if (videoRef.current) {
          videoRef.current.src = videoUrl;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch video:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchVideo();

    return () => {
      // Revoke the video URL when component is unmounted
      if (videoRef.current && videoRef.current.src) {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(videoRef.current.src);
      }
    };
  }, [videoSrc]);

  return (
    <div className="videoWrapper">
      <div className="ambilightWrapper">
        <div className="aspectRatio">
          <video id="video" ref={videoRef} autoPlay muted loop>
            <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        </div>
        <canvas id="ambilight" ref={canvasRef} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoAmbilight;
```

```css
.videoWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ambilightWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}

#ambilight {
  filter: blur(80px) opacity(0.5) saturate(300%);
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(0);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<VideoAmbilight videoSrc="https://cdn...mp4" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Using `window.requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval` helps to avoid some stuttering that may otherwise happen. Make sure to track elapsed time whenever the animation frame callback is invoked and only call `context.drawImage` every `1000 / fps` ms (where `fps` is `30` in this example).

Comment: Here is a simple and clear example on **[codepen](https://codepen.io/mploj/pen/DpOyow)**